# Change the time format for good on ubuntu server

Tags: server, time, date, localization

I've noticed the date is misaligned, namely I got month day, hours and year, all mixed up - obviously I'm having the problem with the inverted date going as month-day-year. The ls command formats month-day, date returns mixed up, etc. I've seen it can be fixed easily in normal gui bylinstallations by changing the localisation. There's plenty of resources on that but every solution starts with "open the property dialog" which obviously is not going to work for me. I've changed the locale in ETC

How can I once and for good change the time format of date to print everything ordered descending(in priority) so *2015 Apr 22 14:00*

I can live with D/M/Y-H/M if it makes it easier, but the current state is really messy. Thanks in advance.

What I tried:

changed my /etc/default/locale to en_DK, but after loging out and in back I haven't found anything changed.
I've tried to manually specify the date format, but I'm concerned about aliasing an actual command with itself isn't possible at all and making date2 won't propagate across the system.

**A note** - perhaps it's actually hard coded and such change would be dangerous to the system?